How to extract User last logged in information using Google Analytics Admin API
We are looking for help to extract the Google Analytics 4 users within our organization and there last accessed date information from Google Analytics Admin API.
Thanks in advance.
We tried exploring the features on the Google Analytics Admin API, unfortunately we couldn't find any solution. I want a list of users who have access to the Google Analytics Property/account and when did they last access those property/account.
